# loading cache to apache ignite failed with exceptions

Tags: ignite

I have couple questions:

1. in local docker runner for web console, I do not see the monitoring, is that only specific to online tool:
2. For online console, I downloaded the java code and tries to run the LoadCaches, but got a lot errors:

[09:13:51,089][SEVERE][mgmt-#47%ImportedCluster1%][GridTaskWorker] Failed to obtain remote job result policy for result from ComputeTask.result(..) method (will fail the whole task): GridJobResultImpl [job=C2 [c=LoadCacheJobV2 [keepBinary=false]], sib=GridJobSiblingImpl [sesId=943eb92f561-a8fe7c19-f1d7-4fae-80ad-6a22fe23707a, jobId=a43eb92f561-a8fe7c19-f1d7-4fae-80ad-6a22fe23707a, nodeId=00d08e30-944b-4ec5-a6d6-a429e142e5f4, isJobDone=false], jobCtx=GridJobContextImpl [jobId=a43eb92f561-a8fe7c19-f1d7-4fae-80ad-6a22fe23707a, timeoutObj=null, attrs={}], node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=00d08e30-944b-4ec5-a6d6-a429e142e5f4, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo0, 10.1.2.120, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/10.1.2.120:47500, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo0:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1537373630293, loc=false, ver=2.5.2#20180622-sha1:cca47098, isClient=false], ex=class o.a.i.IgniteException: Failed to load cache: DepartmentsCache, hasRes=true, isCancelled=false, isOccupied=true]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Remote job threw user exception (override or implement ComputeTask.result(..) method if you would like to have automatic failover for this exception): Failed to load cache: DepartmentsCache
    at org.apache.ignite.compute.ComputeTaskAdapter.result(ComputeTaskAdapter.java:102)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker$5.apply(GridTaskWorker.java:1047)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker$5.apply(GridTaskWorker.java:1040)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.wrapThreadLoader(IgniteUtils.java:6742)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.result(GridTaskWorker.java:1040)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.tas

Is this because my local ignite is not in the same version as the web agent? Online portal gives web agent at 2.4.9, but my local ignite  is at version 2.6, if that is the issue, where is apache ignite v2.4.9?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show more of stack trace? I expect it is not related to use of monitoring tool, your cache store is probably misconfigured.

Answer (score 1):

Monitoring comes with [GridGain Web Console](https://docs.gridgain.com/docs/web-console). It is deployed on [console.gridgain.com](https://console.gridgain.com/) website. It uses GridGain v8.4.9, so you should use it with Ignite 2.4.

If you use an open source [Apache Ignite Web Console](https://apacheignite-tools.readme.io/docs/ignite-web-console), then enterprise features are not available there. But you can deploy it in your environment and use it with any version.